# How to convert or map a Firebase Snapshot child into a custom object in React Native

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get data from Firebase Realtime & display within a FlatList.

What's the best way to capture the child value & map or convert it into my custom object?

Example:

```
class ObjectModel {

    constructor(id, name, age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

export default new ObjectModel();

// on my Screen.js file, getting the data...
useEffect(() => {
    reference
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        
        let data = [];
       
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
          // I need to make the child.val() to be an ObjectModel
          data.push(child.val());
        })

        setArr(data);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to cast a JSON object to a specific type in TypeScript? If so: https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/type-casting/

Answer (score 0):

Try spreading the val like this and then pushing it to your array:

```
let newObjModel = new ObjectModel ({...child.val()})
```

is this is what you were looking for?

Comment: This did not work for me. I get this error -> TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method., js engine: hermes

Comment: @LukeIrvin Try now, edited the code

Comment: New error -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'assign' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Comment: Please try console logging and see the object keys of child.val(), if they have id,name and age, we can use the ObjectModel class.